# Value added by sector of economic activity

Tags: macroeconomics, statistics

I am trying to make a pie chart of value added by economic activity (as a % of gdp). I am trying to use data from world bank for each of the four sectors: manufacturing, agriculture, industry, services http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NV.IND.TOTL.ZS?display=default , but surprisingly the percentage share for each of those sectors, for one country do not add up to 100 but to 120. Why is that?

Comment: Check the definitions... I think you'll find that "manufacturing" is a subset of "industry", so by adding them, you're double-counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your World Bank link gives you the explanation:

> Industry corresponds to ISIC divisions 10-45 and includes
>   manufacturing (ISIC divisions 15-37)

Hence, if you add up industry and manufacturing you count some activities twice, the divisions 15-37 that is.

But even if you take this into account you should not find 100% if you are adding up the value added of all the activities. Gross domestic product (GDP) is not the sum of the gross value added (GVA) of all the activities but:

> GDP = GVA + Taxes on products - Subsidies on products

According to [Statistics Explained](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Glossary:Gross_value_added_at_market_prices)

> Gross value added of the total economy usually accounts for more than
>   90 % of GDP

So, the message is to check carefully the definitions and concepts used by the World Bank.